# Help to ID a bush / mini tree - we think it's euonymus japonicus

Tags: identification

Does anyone have any idea on this please? It's in a large pot, evergreen, completely exposed (1st floor outside ledge, storms, very high wind, 10hrs+ direct sun, winter, summer, etc). It's been docile since we moved in a couple years ago, but suddenly started making these buds.

We think it's euonymus japonicus, and has scale.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image: description]

Comment: To me (steam, leaves, flowers), it seems more like related with Aucuba. Unfortunately I do not know any Aucuba with white/yellowish flowers, and the family has just an other genus (very different).

Comment: It's unlikely to be a Kalanchoe where you live, they're not hardy outdoors here. Are the flowers fragrant? Can you add a photo of the whole plant, including its pot?

Comment: I think you should look into "pittosporum". The flowers look a lot like that. The most common pittosporum I usually see has a different type of leaf (not pointy, but rounded on the end). But, there are a lot of different varieties of that plant, and they are very hardy, as your plant seems to be.

Comment: @Tobin, I think your id is good, if you add an answer to your own question specifying your reasons then readers can vote it up. As you gain more votes/confidence that the id is correct you can accept it as the best answer.

Comment: Certainly the flowers are right for it to be Euonymus - just not sure as to the variety, might be E. japonicus, yea - deciding that was why I thought a second photo might help, but growth is stunted, so still hard to be sure

Answer (score 1):

A good place to start is with the Kalanchoes (wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalanchoe). Unfortunately for identification purposes this opens up a wide range of possibilities since this group is diverse with many species and many varieties in the main species. On the wiki page you can roll mouse over some of the suggested species names and rule many of them out, leaving the main possibility as K. blossfeldiana.

Kalanchoe is a succulent with thick leaves and four part flowers fused into a tube. Note the issues with toxicity mentioned on the wiki page.

Comment: Thanks Colin! The flowers are spot on I think. We've got another Kalanchoe and it's so different! It's got much juicer and oyster leaves.